# does enableLocalhostAuthBypass override --auth ?

Tags: mongodb

In the docs ([link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/)) it says "Specify 0 to disable localhost authentication bypass. Enabled by default" for enableLocalhostAuthBypass. But when I start `mongod` with --auth:

```
mongod --port 30xxx --dbpath=/home/dev/xxxx --auth
```

And then connect via localhost:

```
mongo --host localhost --port 30xxx myDb
```

And then try to do anything:

```
> show collections
Wed Aug  7 11:07:50.420 JavaScript execution failed: error: {
    "$err" : "not authorized for query on configuration.system.namespaces",
    "code" : 16550
```

Bzzt, no go. I can connect with `-u -p` and run `show collections` though.

From the docs it really sounds like connecting via localhost will bypass auth by default. However that's not what I'm seeing. Are the docs unclear? Am I reading it wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`enableLocalhostAuthBypass` is used for the case when you have no user defined at all but with auth enabled on MongoDB and you **don't** want to be able to connect at all. It is not meant to turn off authentication for localhost altogether.

As soon as you have a user defined, then `enabledLocalhostAuthBypass` will do nothing and you have to authenticate first.

It is described in the documentation at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/#authenticate-with-full-administrative-access-via-localhost